# DPLL What is a consistent set of literals?

Tags: algorithm, sat, sat-solvers, dpll

I am writing a SAT solver and I started implementing a DPLL algorithm. I understand the algorithm and how it works, I also implemented a variation of it, but what bothers me is the next thing.

```
function DPLL(Φ)
   if Φ is a consistent set of literals
       then return true;
   if Φ contains an empty clause
       then return false;
   for every unit clause l in Φ
      Φ ← unit-propagate(l, Φ);
   for every literal l that occurs pure in Φ
      Φ ← pure-literal-assign(l, Φ);
   l ← choose-literal(Φ);
   return DPLL(Φ ∧ l) or DPLL(Φ ∧ not(l));
```

What does it mean, that *`Φ` is a consistent set of literals*? I understand that **inconsistent implies false**, meaning that **consistent implies not false**. So why can we return `true` if the current assignment doesn't falsify the problem?

The way I implemented my SAT solver is, that whenever it comes across the assignment that made all clauses true, I returned that assignment and the algorithm was done. But since for given assignment, all clauses must be true in order for it to be a solution to the problem, I don't understand, how can one return `true` in case that an assignment **just satisfies** the problem (I assume I am getting something wrong here, but since if `Φ` is consistent, then it means it is not false, but it can still be undecidable?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Φ is a consistent set of literals when it contains only literals and a literal and its negation does not appear in Φ.  The DPLL algorithm, through the pure and unit rules, gradually converts the list of clauses into a list of literals that satisfy all the original clauses.  The algorithm is done when that happens (Φ is a consistent set of literals) or when it runs out of literal assignments to try and the topmost DPLL call returns false.

Comment: That's what i expected, I was just bothered with the definition of consistency that I was not sure if that is what it meant. Thanks a lot. I also need to return the satisfactory assignment, so I assume i just print the current assignment when phi is consistent